# AngularStrap datepicker doesn't work when the date is typed (keyboard input)

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-strap

I have an issue with the AngularStrap datepicker (bs-datepicker directive)..

When a date is selected using the popup datepicker - no problem.

When a date is typed (keyboard) and if the input dateformat is different from the config, the model doesn't get updated. I am not sure if this is how its supposed to work but I am sure the users wont mind just typing in the date instead of using the mouse clicks to select a date.

**here is my html**

```
<div class="control-group input-append">
  <input type="text" ng-model="datepicker.date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
</div>
```

User types in 01/01/1998 - no problem.

User types in 01-01-1998 - doesnt work, the model doesnt get updated.

**Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1pnd10cdcILzs4O5VEur?p=preview)**

Any help is appreciated. The work around I could think of is to make the the input readonly but thats a bad idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an Angular issue, it appears to be the way the library works.  Do you have it working the way you expect outside Angular?  If so, show a plunker for that too.

Comment: Nope, I didnt mean its Angular issue (did I mention it somewhere!). Its probably an issue with the bs-datepicker directive and Im looking for someone who can give useful answers!